# How many kinds of guns have been used in Highschool of the Dead?

Tags: highschool-of-the-dead

I wonder how many guns have been shown to be used by the characters?
And are these real guns? Or are these just some made-up weapons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [wikia page](https://highschool-of-the-dead.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Guns), there are about 14 unique guns shown in the anime.

- Armalite AR-10(T)
- Barnett Wildcat C5
- Benelli M4 Super 90
- CZE Vz83
- FN Browning M1910
- Heckler & Koch PSG-1
- Ithaca M37
- Kiku Crest Luger P08
- M92 Vertec
- MP5SFK
- Nail Gun
- SIG Sauer P226
- Smith & Wesson M37 Air Weight
- Springfield M1A1 Super Match

To add, yes, these are real guns. I was able to find real-world counterparts of all of these guns via Google. To note, the [Luger P08](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luger_pistol#Pistole_Modell_1908_(P08)_and_World_War_I) seems to be a gun used during the world wars and CZE Vz83 seems to be a [Skorpion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0korpion).